# HTML/CSS Making 3 divs line up next to each other with one with flexible width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align 3 divs next to each other, with 2 flexible width and 1 fixed width.
Please see the following jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qyGC5/82/

I've seen this post: [Three DIVs next to each other with fluid horizontal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826542/three-divs-next-to-each-other-with-fluid-horizontal-width)
but it doesn't work with 2 flexible divs or even with just 1 flexible width (the one with the long text). http://jsfiddle.net/qyGC5/89/

I also though of percentages, but since using 100% is out of the question, the gap would get bigger or smaller on resize.

Any help, much appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDITED**
Adding some screen shots to show what happens after I ajax load new comments (this is to display comments)

BEFORE THE AJAX LOAD MORE COMMENTS
[image: This is before the AJAX load, looks perfect]

AFTER THE AJAX LOAD
[image]

Comment: It takes jsFiddle longer to load than it does me to write the answer..

Comment: How many flexible `div`s are there supposed to be? You switch between saying 1 and 2.

Comment: Best would be 2 flexible divs.

Comment: So the two `.sides` should be flexible and `#main` should be fixed, or?

Comment: @thirtydot: modified the jsfiddle to explain better, it works fine in the fiddle, but doesn't work on my site, which has exactly the same configuration: http://jsfiddle.net/qyGC5/99/

Answer (score 4):

Forget about using `display: inline-block` for this.

Use `float: left` on `.sides` [and `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) on `#main`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/qyGC5/93/

```
<div class="sides">side 1</div>
<div class="sides">side 2</div>
<div id="main">Lorem ipsum..</div>

.sides {
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px dotted green;

    float: left;
}
#main {
    border: 2px dotted blue;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What's the `overflow: hidden` for though?

Comment: @Supr: Did you try removing `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: I would recommend http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ for clearing floats. :-)

Comment: I did, and didn't notice any difference, but turns out it was because jsfiddle was stuck loading :/ When I tried again I could see why. Sorry :) Still don't understand _why_ it works though...

Comment: @Supr: No problem, I just complained about the same thing myself in a comment on the question. I've since edited a link into my answer explaining why this works.

Comment: @meep: I tend to switch between [that](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) and `overflow: hidden` as I deem appropriate. In this instance though, there's no float clearing happening. `overflow: hidden` is being used [for something else](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Comment: @thirtydot:  Thanks for the anser, works like a charm until I AJAX load some content.  When that happens seems like the text doesn't go to the line anymore.  Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @denislexic: There's no reason that adding content to any of those `div`s should cause it to break. Can you show me a demo of the broken behaviour?

Comment: @thirtydot: Unfortunately it's only on my local server for the moment. but I added some printscreens to illustrate.  Thanks.

Comment: @thirtydot: I found out that the issue comes from when a text has no spaces, it doesn't wrap the text.  ie: if someone types "AAAAA...(x50)...A) the text doesn't go to the line so it just pushes...Any idea on how to solve that?  Thanks.